# asp.net gridview update with dropdownlist

Tags: asp.net, gridview, drop-down-menu, sqldatasource

I have a gridview that pulls data from an sqldatasource and I when clicking Edit I want to add a dropdownlist instead of a textbox. The values of the dropdownlist must be preset as below (not pulled from the DB)

Here is the gridview template code:

```
<asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Priority" SortExpression="Priority">
   <EditItemTemplate>
        <asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownList1" runat="server" 
         DataTextField='<%# Bind("Priority") %>' 
         DataValueField='<%# Bind("Priority") %>' 
         DataSource='<%# Bind("Priority") %>' >
         <asp:ListItem>1:High</asp:ListItem>
         <asp:ListItem>2:Medium</asp:ListItem>
         <asp:ListItem>3:Low</asp:ListItem>
        </asp:DropDownList>
   </EditItemTemplate>
   <ItemTemplate>
       <asp:Label ID="lblPriority" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("Priority") %>'></asp:Label>
   </ItemTemplate>
</asp:TemplateField>
```

I keep getting errors similar to this:

> DataBinding: 'System.Char' does not contain a property with the name '3:Low'.

Can anyone see from above what is the cause?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have bounded the DropDownList to the Priority field in the database.  Therefore every Priority must contain one of the following values:

```
1:High
2:Medium
3:Low
```

Could it be that the Priority field contains an integer i.e. 1,2,3 or a value i.e. high,medium,low instead of: '1:High', '2:Medium'.'3:Low'?

If this is not the case, then please provide some sample values from the priority field.

Comment: priority is varchar(10) in the Db, can that be the cause? should it not pick it up as a string?

Comment: I don't think so.  What are the distinct values in that field?

Comment: The DB Priority field has one of three: 1:High, 2:Medium or 3:Low. I have gotten it to sort of work by adding a second lookup table with the three priorities and an ID for each, then in the main table I have Priority_ID instead of Priority. It updates just fine but it displays the ID now which is not what I want. I know to show it I would need: `select Priority_Type from CERecord, CEPriority where Priority_ID=Priority and ID=1` but how to bind that to a single label?

Comment: Got it to work in the end, thanks to this example http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms972948.aspx